# Trying to make a telnet gui with telnetlib

Tags: python, user-interface, telnet, telnetlib

First of all this is my first question on that site so i may make some basic mistakes, apologies in advance. Anyway i tried to make a GUI for telnet and i used python3 as programming language. However i wanted to make a continuous connection, sadly i could not get any output until i stopped the program( tn.write(b"exit\n") ). i am open to every kind of feedback (like you should use sockets or so ...)  any info that you give will be appreciated.
Ps: i only tried to connect localhost so far and i only filled the connection button. 
Ps2:Somehow i couldn't even managed to fit the code completely sorry.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib



def main():

    root= Tk()

    def tel_net():

        username = entry1.get()
        pw = entry2.get()
        host_ip= entry3.get()           

        HOST = host_ip
        user = username 
        password = pw

        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

        tn.read_until(b"login: ")
        tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        if password:
            tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
            tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

        tn.write(b"ls\n")
        tn.write(b"exit\n")
        print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii')

    def printconnect():

        print("connected")  
        tel_net()       

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("telnet", "connected")

    def printdisconnect():  
        print("disconnected")
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
        tn.close(HOST)      

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("telnet","disconnected")
    def quitwindow():
        answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("telnet","Do you want to quit ?")
        if answer == "yes": 
            root.destroy()  

    button1 = Button(root, text="Connect", command=printconnect, fg="green")
    button2 = Button(root, text="Disconnect", command=printdisconnect, fg="red")
    button3 = Button(root, text="Exit", command=quitwindow, fg="purple")


    button1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky = E)
    button2.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky = E)
    button3.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky = E)



    label1 = Label(root, text="Username")
    label2 = Label(root, text= "Password")
    label3 = Label(root, text="Host ip")



    entry1 = Entry(root)
    entry2 = Entry(root)
    entry3 = Entry(root)
    entry2.config(show="*");

    label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = W)
    label2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = W)
    label3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky = W)

    entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = W)
    entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky = W)
    entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky = W)

    c1=Checkbutton(root, text="Remember username")
    c1.grid(columnspan=2,sticky = W)
    c2=Checkbutton(root, text="Remember password")
    c2.grid(columnspan=2,sticky = W)
    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the telnet communications is blocking you need to put the actual communications into a separate thread from the GUI. You also need to put a timeout on all read operations and then check if you have any write operations to perform between reads.